# React componentDidMount does not show axios response

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have React component RandomQouteMachine which is supposed to get response from the provided URL and display it on the page. I don't see response displayed. The debug 'Did component mount ?' message is missing too..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 
lass RandomQouteMachine extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: ""
    };    
  }

  componenetDidMount() {
    console.log('Did component mount ?');
    axios.get('https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random')
      .then((res) => {       
        this.setState({data:res.value.joke});
      })

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Here it is:
      {this.state.data}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RandomQouteMachine;
```

Am I using  componenetDidMount() correctly ? I can see only **'Here it is:'** displayed on page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check your spelling.

componenetDidMount !== componentDidMount

Comment: Great, appreciate;) Maybe you can also help with TypeError: Cannot read property 'joke' of undefined. Axios response should get me json

Comment: you are attempting to get your data from res.value. If you look at the documentation from the axios website you need to get the info from res.data